# How do I fix try except error on employee time sheet?

Tags: python

I have a program the functions correctly but I have to add error checking and now I am running into an issue. The problem is that if you type in a number for the worker_name then the following time you type in a name, once you go through all of the input fields it prints out the "Production worker information" twice. How do I fix this?

Entire program:

```
class Employee(object):

    def __init__(self, name, id_number):
        self.id_number = id_number
        self.name = name

class Worker(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, id_number, shift_number, pay_rate):
        #call superclass __init__ method
        Employee.__init__(self, name, id_number)
        #initialize shift_number and pay_rate attributes
        self.shift_number = shift_number
        self.pay_rate = pay_rate


def main():
    #variables
    worker_name= " "
    worker_id = " "
    worker_shift = 0
    worker_pay = 0.00

    #get data attributes

    while 1:
        try:
            worker_name = input("Enter the worker name: ")
            print()
            if not worker_name.isalpha():
                print("Only letters are allowed!")
                print()
                main()
                break
            worker_id = int(input("Enter the ID number: "))
            print()
            worker_shift = int(input("Enter the shift number: "))
            print()
            worker_pay = float(input("Enter the hourly pay rate: "))
            print()
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()
            
    #create an instance of Worker
    Employee.worker = worker_name, worker_id, worker_shift, worker_pay
    if not worker_name.isalpha():
        pass
    #display information
    print ("Production worker information ")
    print("---------------------------------")
    print()
    print ("Name: ", worker_name)
    print()
    print ("ID number: ", worker_id)
    print()
    print ("Shift: ", worker_shift)
    print()
    print ("Hourly Pay Rate: $ " + format(worker_pay, ",.2f"))

main()
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem into a [mre]. 
Then ask a specific question. Pasting your entire code here is a great way to get people to lose interest in your question.

Comment: A little side note, `while True` is the more idiomatic way of doing a continuos loop in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are recursively calling `main()` instead of allowing the `while 1:` loop to work.

I think you meant:

```py
            if not worker_name.isalpha():
                print("Only letters are allowed!")
                print()
                continue
```

The `continue` will jump back to the `while 1:`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call again `main()` inside itself, use you `try/except` system

```
def main():
    #variables
    worker_name, worker_id, worker_shift,worker_pay = "", "", 0, 0

    while True:
        try:
            worker_name = input("Enter the worker name: ")
            if not worker_name.isalpha():
                print("\nOnly letters are allowed!")
                continue

            worker_id = int(input("\nEnter the ID number: "))
            worker_shift = int(input("\nEnter the shift number: "))
            worker_pay = float(input("\nEnter the hourly pay rate: "))
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e), "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the loop to retry the input if it fails (rather than calling recursively).  You can also take advantage of `try/catch` to make the code quite a bit shorter -- just `try` the whole thing you want to do in order to create the `worker` and then you don't need to separately declare and check each variable one at a time.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name: str, id_number: int):
        assert name.isalpha(), "Only letters are allowed in employee names!"
        self.id_number = id_number
        self.name = name


class Worker(Employee):
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        id_number: int,
        shift_number: int,
        pay_rate: float
    ):
        # call superclass __init__ method
        Employee.__init__(self, name, id_number)
        # initialize shift_number and pay_rate attributes
        self.shift_number = shift_number
        self.pay_rate = pay_rate


def main():
    # create an instance of Worker
    while True:
        try:
            name = input("\nEnter the worker name: ")
            assert name.isalpha(), "Only letters are allowed!"  # fail fast!
            worker = Worker(
                name,
                int(input("\nEnter the ID number: ")),
                int(input("\nEnter the shift number: ")),
                float(input("\nEnter the hourly pay rate: "))
            )
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Invalid choice! try again! {e}\n")

    # display information
    print(f"""
Production worker information
---------------------------------

Name: {worker.name}

ID number: {worker.id_number}

Shift: {worker.shift_number}

"Hourly Pay Rate: ${worker.pay_rate:.2f}
""")


main()
```